# Validating raw_input inside a for loop

Tags: python

I'm attempting to create a validation loop to check a user input against a defined list, but for some reason the code gets stuck in a loop perpetually asking the user to re-enter the value. I tested by adding a print command into the loop and the input data is being stored to the attributes dictionary, but it never seem to meet the == criteria to trigger the break from the for loop.

Here's my code so far, would really appreciate any suggestions on where I'm going amiss:

```
attributes = {'Name': 'None', 'Class': 'None', 'Strength': 3, 'Agility': 3, 'Wounds': 3, 'Intelligence': 3}

attributes['Name'] = raw_input('What is your character\'s name?')
attributes['Class'] = raw_input('Choose your character\'s class, enter Warrior, Mage, Ranger or Thief.')

#this is the section I am struggling with!
for values in attributes:
    if attributes['Class'] != "Warrior" or "Mage" or "Ranger" or "Thief":
        attributes['Class'] = raw_input('Please choose either Warrior, Mage, Ranger or Thief.')
        continue
    elif attributes['Class'] == "Warrior" or "Mage" or "Ranger" or "Thief":
        break

if attributes["Class"] == "Warrior":
    attributes["Strength"] += 1
    attributes["Wounds"] += 1
elif attributes["Class"] == "Mage":
    attributes["Intelligence"] += 2
elif attributes["Class"] == "Ranger":
    attributes["Strength"] += 1
    attributes["Agility"] += 1
elif attributes["Class"] == "Thief":
    attributes["Agility"] += 1
    attributes["Intelligence"] += 1

print
print 'Name: ' + attributes['Name']
print 'Class: ' + attributes['Class']
print 'STR: ' + str(attributes['Strength']), 'AGI: ' + str(attributes['Agility']), 'WOU: ' + str(attributes['Wounds']) ,'INT: ' + str(attributes['Intelligence'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
if attributes['Class'] != "Warrior" or "Mage" or "Ranger" or "Thief":
```

will always resolve to `True` because `bool("Mare") == True` so your loop never breaks.

What I think you are looking for is something closer to:

```
if attributes['Class'] not in ("Warrior", "Mage", "Ranger", "Thief"):
```

If you are just trying to check the value of `attributes['Class']`, the following loop might be more appropriate:

```
while attributes['Class'] not in ("Warrior", "Mage", "Ranger", "Thief"):
    attributes['Class'] = raw_input('Please choose either Warrior, Mage, Ranger or Thief.')
```

Answer (score 1):

The `or` works different than you think. 
It gives you the first value that is true. In Python non-empty strings are always true. Therefore:

```
>>> "Warrior" or "Mage" or "Ranger" or "Thief"
'Warrior'
```

Change your code to:

```
if attributes['Class'] not in ("Warrior", "Mage", "Ranger", "Thief"):
    attributes['Class'] = raw_input('Please choose either Warrior, Mage, Ranger or Thief.')
    continue
else:
    break
```

This checks if the entered input is in the names in your tuple. If not, it asks for new input, otherwise it stops asking for input.

Answer (score 1):

Your OR should be AND in the first IF. You would have to do them as:

```
if attributes['Class'] != "Warrior" and attributes['Class'] != "Mage" and attributes['Class'] != "Ranger" and attributes['Class'] != "Thief"
```

An easier way to do this would to look for them in a list:

```
for values in attributes:
    if attributes['Class'] not in ["Warrior", "Mage", "Ranger", "Thief"]:
        attributes['Class'] = raw_input('Please choose either Warrior, Mage, Ranger or Thief.')
        continue
    elif attributes['Class'] in ["Warrior", "Mage", "Ranger", "Thief"]:
        break
```